# ¿Cómo Resetear Auto Incremento en Django con SQLite?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-admin

Estoy Programando en Django y me encuentro con el inconveniente.
El siguiente modelo es mi tabla dentro del archivo **models.py** de la aplicación:
from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
class Country(models.Model):
    id_country = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name_country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='country'
        verbose_name_plural='countries'
```

Dentro del archivo **admin.py** definí de la siguiente forma:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Country

# Register your models here.
class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["name_country"]
    list_display = ("id_country","name_country")

admin.site.register(Country,CountryAdmin)
```

Desde la interfaz de admin que provee Django puedo ingresar sin problemas registros a la base de datos, sin embargo, si ingreso un registro, luego lo elimino y agrego un nuevo registro, el autoincremento sigue aumentando. Mi propósito es que al eliminar un registro por ejemplo con id 5, y vuelva a agregar un nuevo registro, este último tenga el id 5 en vez de 6 (ya que el ultimo registro con id 5 fue eliminado). Estuve buscando como obtener este resultado y por el momento no encontré solución, ¿Hay una forma de conseguirlo?

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea posible, SQLite impones muchas restricciones para editar una tabla ya creada. Pero no estoy 100% seguro de ello.

Pero más importante, es que es una muy mala idea hacer lo que quieres. En principio parece razonable deshacer el `autoincrement` en el último registro, pero que pasa si lo que estas borrando es un registro del medio? Se forma un lio, imagina que ese campo se FK de otra tabla, habría que sobreescribir todas esas otras tablas tambien.

Y en todo caso, el uso de `autoincrement` es prescindible en muchos casos y se desaconseja su uso.

No obstante, SQLite tiene una característica que puede ayudarte que es `rowid`, que mantiene un identificador autoincrementable por fila.

Por ejemplo creamos una tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE test(a INT, b TEXT);
```

Luego insertamos datos

```
INSERT into test(a,b) values
(1,"223"),
(2,"223"),
(3,"223"),
(4,"223");
```

Realizamos un select y agregamos una consulta al `rowid`:

`select rowid, * from test`

| rowid | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 2 | 123 |
| 3 | 3 | 123 |
| 4 | 4 | 123 |

Luego

- Borramos el registro a=2 `DELETE FROM test where a=2`
- Agregamos un quinto registro `INSERT into test(a,b) values(5,"223");`
- Volvemos a hacer el mismo select

| rowid | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 3 | 3 | 123 |
| 4 | 4 | 123 |
| 5 | 5 | 123 |

Como verás no hubo modificación en los anteriores, es decir perdemos para siempre el rowid=2, que como señalaba al principio es lo correcto.
Ahora otro caso, donde borramos el último dato

- Borramos el **ÚLTIMO** registro con a=5 `DELETE FROM test where a=5`
- Agregamos un sexto registro `INSERT into test(a,b) values(6,"223");`
- Volvemos a hacer el mismo select

| rowid | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 3 | 3 | 123 |
| 4 | 4 | 123 |
| 5 | **6** | 123 |

Veras que en este caso si recicla el último ID, lo cual entiendo es exactamente lo que buscas

Fuente: [Documentación](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)